# Get topic rate from my node

Tags: ros, roscpp, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all! I have a node subscribed to a topic. In principle, the topic rate is constant but unknown from the node. Does exist a method to get the rate of this topic from my node program? Something similar to use "$rostopic hz" from console but from the code program.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228424/get-topic-rate-from-my-node/) by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic has an API as documented on the wiki page (http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic). However, it does give a warning that "This library is for internal-use only as the code API may change, though it does provide examples of how to implement dynamic subscription and publication behaviors in ROS." so your mileage may vary.

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2016-03-07**:
Thank you very much, this is that I'm looking for (*ROSTopicHz* class). However, your reflexion is very interesting and maybe I should implement directly an initial callback to estimate the topic rate and after that replace it for the original, better than use this class directly. Thanks alee!